# Paypal Payment Selection | 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, paypal, request, payment

i just try to load the payment selection from paypal. In my case i get my access token, create a "payment" to get the "approval_url" (all good so far) and send everything to get the selections.

I used this tutorial: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf

I used the following code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        approvalUrl: "my_approval_url",
        placeholder: "ppplus",
        mode: "sandbox",
        payerEmail: "test@test.com",
        payerFirstName: "Test",
        payerLastName: "Tester",
        payerTaxId: "Test",
    });
</script>
```

And the script starts request here:
[image]

Here are the **response** headers:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 978
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com; font-src 'self' https://*.paypalobjects.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.paypalobjects.com; script-src 'nonce-CdSg/AfsURJw5QsVZ4E/gK6JzEPjMzWjQAuh/gLWnKf47ThS' 'self' https://*.paypal.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.paypalobjects.com; img-src 'self' *.paypal.com http://www.paypalobjects.com https://www.paypalobjects.com data: https://*.paypal.com https://*.stats.paypal.com; media-src 'self' ; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://*.qualtrics.com; frame-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.qualtrics.com; child-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com; form-action 'self' https://*.paypal.com; base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com; block-all-mixed-content;
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 11:31:26 GMT
etag: W/"3d2-GSx74LGXIWFtOh0MGCT5JtUl8JI"
p3p: ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL
paypal-debug-id: a60312f3bcf0c
set-cookie: enforce_policy=gdpr_v2.1; Max-Age=31536000; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 28 Jul 2022 11:31:25 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: LANG=de_DE%3BDE; Max-Age=31556; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 28 Jul 2021 20:17:21 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: cookie_prefs=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: cookie_prefs=T%3D1%2CP%3D1%2CF%3D1%2Ctype%3Dexplicit_banner; Max-Age=31536000; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 28 Jul 2022 11:31:25 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: x-pp-s=eyJ0IjoiMTYyNzQ3MTg4NTkzNiIsImwiOiIxIiwibSI6IjAifQ; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: ts=vreXpYrS%3D1722166285%26vteXpYrS%3D1627473685%26vr%3Db72a7aee1750a1d32f1d6a65ff1c3640%26vt%3Deca4d0dc17a0a280d045f077fe2e1e2c%26vtyp%3Dreturn; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Sat, 27 Jul 2024 11:31:25 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: ts_c=vr%3Db72a7aee1750a1d32f1d6a65ff1c3640%26vt%3Deca4d0dc17a0a280d045f077fe2e1e2c; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Sat, 27 Jul 2024 11:31:25 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: x-cdn=fastly:HHN; Domain=paypal.com; Path=/; Secure
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
via: 1.1 varnish
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: ALLOWALL
x-served-by: cache-hhn4080-HHN
x-timer: S1627471886.746432,VS0,VE265
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

And here are the request headers:

```
:authority: www.sandbox.paypal.com
:method: POST
:path: /inlinepaymentwall/payment-selection
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 499
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: cookie_check=yes; d_id=c728f16b487043c0a6464fb6c64000991615979487284; cookie_prefs=T%3D1%2CP%3D1%2CF%3D1%2Ctype%3Dexplicit_banner; _gcl_au=1.1.1578755987.1623044189; enforce_policy=gdpr_v2.1; nsid=s%3Ako-oTVP541J2T4CYheX_2nL3rzGF36nb.yp%2BPxeDyk11Rkdv0CESe%2FvtC0JDgrm0bsvknQ6cW7%2Bk; _gcl_aw=GCL.1627381563.Cj0KCQjw3f6HBhDHARIsAD_i3D9k7-L9aIT1wRARAjzPAjLVib5wsvb8ClzQ_NKqhsTatstPcnt3mEMaArx5EALw_wcB; login_email=stuff.de; ui_experience=login_type%3DEfffff3D3; _gcl_dc=GCL.1627382705.COvt8v-Ig_ICFQ6vewodOnkISg; LANG=de_DE%3BDE; ts_c=vr%3Db72a7aee1750a1d32f1d6a65ff1c3640%26vt%3Deca4d0dc17a0a280d045f077fe2e1e2c; fn_dt=2c1e960cea604a47b4cc51db3157ab95; SEGM=; X-PP-ADS=AToBZ97.YCR6YKA3utw0Grtb842yRDc7AYAyAWG4DPdC3h7mVdkmqlkVfspK; id_token=; KHcl0EuY7AKSMgfvHl7J5E7hPtK=wQPYRUtB-0B_t2rebSF1DnWgzNLqT7GfK2DGCHr__BjqW7l6-yoolNLy-hfOXatKW3ei50U1bZhj8haB; AV894Kt2TSumQQrJwe-8mzmyREO=S23AAMKJNiWu7IkZBw0oYXcOqOaUumcmtUkZCQh7AP6ZI_VWFKj7hotZ9lWVZySWO9h-vbImFatUsRE8LlnAxieYCoMygsfWQ; rmuc=PKL9MFIyEnV4d3A93jqoWdGD6YH-4tQGDT4Ij6VP0ayt6APsFD5WOpqEh13iKGAvNmbOPtq8OP70gU_p72OYeZxUlIU_t4TsM9eFWwu-3zpWkk2yiwfbMDCOup07pqKE4dzCpJND3TCr_T3J_fKZZISaZAuK_8MPB8v-nM0-LeEgFzSN7iw4ejOD_QSniNV40Y6B60; DPz73K5mY4nlBaZpzRkjI3ZzAY3QMmrP=S23AAMKJNiWu7IkZBw0oYXcOqOaUumcmtUkZCQh7AP6ZI_VWFKj7hotZ9lWVZySWO9h-vbImFatUsRE8LlnAxieYCoMygsfWQ; HaC80bwXscjqZ7KM6VOxULOB534=ChGpwxJ85fGXpP2VwrXiBZygqV097FFnYWnW7eM4CDo3fELGLI-RIDDSIaDRcoXp9G2GRxZ5XxcGrrJ05HnRODpohdPkyBgW5UG_lzWi4szkI1N0CF4Lv12zLcOSAwOYn_ocAm; tsrce=ppplusbrcpmnodeweb; x-pp-s=eyJ0IjoiMTYyNzQ3MTg4NDI4OCIsImwiOiIxIiwibSI6IjAifQ; ts=vreXpYrS%3D1722166284%26vteXpYrS%3D1627473684%26vr%3Db72a7aee1750a1d32f1d6a65ff1c3640%26vt%3Deca4d0dc17a0a280d045f077fe2e1e2c%26vtyp%3Dreturn
origin: https://stufffff.de
referer: https://stufffff.de/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: iframe
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
```

But everytime i receive the 403 Forbidden State and i dont know why.
I already receive some js errors. You can find them here:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/e13/29de9ba9019423c167bdd418d7b5b' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com".
```

Comment: I have the same problem... were you able to solve?